# An `if` and `while` statement in the same line of C, without an apparent branch or loop

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm browsing a project on Github, and a line that I can't make sense of is present in one of the files.

The line itself is,

```
if(!*p) while(*c++ != ']');
```

... So I *think* I understand that the `while` gets executed `if(!*p)`, but the while doesn't have any corresponding loop, which sort of puzzles me.

What does this statement mean?

For context: [the line in the file](https://github.com/L8D/delvs/blob/master/delvs.h#L53)

Comment: Note that the symbol p is #define'd as g->pointer, and the symbol c is #define'd as g->code, so the line of code (after pre-processing) is equivalent to: if( !*(g->pointer) ) { while(*(g->code)++ != ']') {} }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `;` simply ends the single line while statement, without doing anything. This code could alternately be written as the following:

```
if(!*p) while(*c++ != ']'){}
```

Basically, the while statements continues until the return value of `*c++` does not equal the `]` character, presumably with the intent of seeking forward past the next `]` character.

On a side note, there is no bounds checking in this loop, so it could seek past the intended address space, which could be bad.

Comment: ... seeking forward to just past the next `]`

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does! It increments the pointer: `*c` with:

```
*c++
```

And the semicolon is the 'body' of the while loop which simple does nothing

Comment: @Bot I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: check the link he added

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to:

```
if(!*p)
{
    while(*c++ != ']'){}
}
```

So it is basically incrementing the character pointer until it points to that ']' character.
Thanks to Rici for pointing out a mistake in the code

Comment: @rici Took me a bit to understand what you mean. Is it that when it evaluates the *c++ in the while condition, it increments it first before stepping into the loop?

Comment: @Abbath: precisely. So your loop, c points to the ], but in the code c points to just past the ]. Those are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
`while(*c++ != ']');`
```

Means   `while(*c++ != ']'){  }`
 if There is nothing inside the Body of the loop, we can put  " ; " as in the first code above.So the Code in your question is really like

```
if(!*p) {  while(*c++ != ']') { }  }
```